# Saxon. XPathSelector. XPathException: Cannot compare xs:untypedAtomic to xs:decimal

Tags: saxon

When I use saxon9-he (version 9.8.0.6) for XPath in an application on Net Framwork, there is an error "net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Can not compare xs: untypedAtomic to xs: decimal".

This occurs when XPathSelector evaluates an expression using the "Evaluate" method.
The expression itself looks like this: matches ($ var1 / text (), '^ [0-9] {1,2} . [0-9] {2} $') or ($ var1 eq 100.0).

Variable "var1" is set in XPathSelector by the SetVariable method as XdmNode.

I ask you to suggest a possible way out of this situation.

Comment: Consider to show minimal but complete snippets of  the XML and C# or VB.NET code to allow others to reproduce the problem. I guess the culprit is `$var1 eq 100.0`, for a quick change I would suggest to try `$var1 = 100.0` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The "=" operator converts an xs:untypedAtomic operand to the type of the other operand. The "eq" operator does not.

The reason for this is to make "eq" transitive, so it works sensibly for indexing, grouping, etc.

So you should either do a manual conversion:

```
xs:decimal($var1) eq 100.0
```

or use the "=" operator:

```
$var1 = 100.0
```

By the way, you're welcome to ask Saxon questions either here or on the Saxon forums, but please don't ask the same question on both: it wastes everyone's time.